# Shuffling array according to assigned random values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I watched a [video disscussing a shuffling algorithm that runs at O(nlogn)](https://youtu.be/4zx5bM2OcvA?t=111)
The following python code is given:

```
def shuffle(arr):
      rand_values = [random.random() for i in range(len(arr))]
      rand_indexes = [i for i in range(len(arr))]
      rand_indexes.sort(key=lambda i: rand_values[i])
      arr = [arr[i] for i in rand_indexes]
```

In the method an array of random values is created eg `[57,12,84,5,71]`
An array of index is created eg `[0,1,2,3,4]`
Then the index array is sorted accroing to the rand values eg `[3,1,0,4,2]`
Finally the array is shuffled using the random indexes array eg if arr = `[H,o,w,d,y]` it would be shuffled as `[d,o,H,y,w]`

I am trying to get the same algrothim working in Java so it still runs in O(nlogn) without using any packages besides Random

What I have at the moment:

```
public void shuffle(Object[] a) {
        if (a.length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        int size = a.length;
        Random rand = new Random();
        Comparable[] randValues = new Comparable[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            randValues[i] = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        
        Object randIndex[] = new Object[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            randIndex[i] = i;
        }
        
        Comparable[] sortedArr = mergesort(randValues);
        //mergesort is a seperate sorting method with param Comparable[] a
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                randIndex[i] = sortedArr[i];
            }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int index = (int) randIndex[i];
            a[i] =  a[index];
        }
        
    }
```

Currently, I am stuck trying to sort the `randIndex` array based of the random values.

Comment: Why is `randValues` a `Comparable[]` instead of `Integer[]`?

Comment: So I could run it through my mergesort method

Comment: You can still pass it. `Integer[]` is a subclass of `Comparable[]`. (Plus it's not a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1553851).)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the built-in sorting capabilities and the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

```
import java.util.Random;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

String[] names = {"James", "Oliver", "Liam", "Noah", "Ethan", "Lucas", "Henry", "Owen", "Leo", "Mason"};
Random rand = new Random();

Arrays.sort(names, comparing(s -> rand.nextInt()));
```

The static `Comparators.comparing` function creates a `Comparator` from a given lambda function that, in this case, merely needs to return some random number.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't import any packages other than java.util.Random

Comment: Oh well in that case I don't care.